# How to call the RefreshTableView function in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I wrote a Refresh function to reload the tableview in iPhone app with the argument of UITableview.
My question is how can I call or invoke this refresh function?

```
- (void)RefreshTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    if(tableView != nil){
       [tableView reloadData]; 
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to check objects to see if they are `nil` before sending messages to them.  Messages to `nil` are ignored.

Comment: I'm doing a joke iphone app in that the home page is listing the category from jokescategory table in database. I have settings to disable the category its working perfectly

Comment: I'm doing a joke app in that the home page is listing the category from jokescategory table from database. I have settings to disable the category the table updating working perfectly. But the problem is The RootView(home page) not getting reloaded. Its getting reloaded when run the app again. So How can I reload the RootView?    I tried [tablView reloadData] and [self.tableView reloadData]   I have two tables in DB one for category(jokescategory) and another one for joke(jokesbody). Both the table getting updated successfully but the RootView not reloaded. so how can I reload the RootView?

Comment: @Jim see my command I need your help..

Comment: It's inappropriate for you to leave multiple comments asking individuals to help you.  If you have a new problem, post a new question.  Don't ask everybody you've interacted with in the past to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all rename your method like the following:

```
- (void)refreshTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Then, to call that method you need to perform the following:

```
[self refreshTableView:yourTableview];
```

where `self` stands for the object that will receive the message. In this case `self` is an instance of the object that contains that method.

Now, why do you need to pass also an instance of the table view?

if you have a instance variable for that table view and you have synthesized it (`@property/@synthesize` pattern), you could simple do the following:

```
- (void)refreshTableView
{
    [[self myTable] reloadData];
}
```

and then invoke that method like the following:

```
[self refreshTableView];
```

**Edit**

As **danh** suggested, if you have a property (or an instance variable), you can also call directly

```
[[self myTable] reloadData]; // or [self.myTable reloadData];
```

without passing through `refreshTableView`.

Comment: +1 for trimming it down.  I would +1 it one more time (if I could) if you point out that the function is unnecessary.  Replace with [self.myTable reloadData];

Comment: I'm doing a joke app in that the home page is listing the category from jokescategory table from database. I have settings to disable the category the table updating working perfectly. But the problem is The RootView(home page) not getting reloaded. Its getting reloaded when run the app again. So How can I reload the RootView?    I tried [tablView reloadData] and [self.tableView reloadData]   I have two tables in DB one for category(jokescategory) and another one for joke(jokesbody). Both the table getting updated successfully but the RootView not reloaded. so how can I reload the RootView?

Comment: @rajesh Could you explain better your goal? Maybe put an edit in your question and provide more code. Thank you.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted I have posted my question in following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333897/how-can-i-reload-the-tableview-that-listed-in-rootviewcontroller-m-from-category)

Answer (score 0):

If `- (void)RefreshTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` is in the same file then you can call it

`[self RefreshTableView:aTableView];` when you want to call.

Comment: thank you..but its throws the error aTableView not declared and also did tried tableView it also throws error

Comment: @rajesh: at where u have declared table view ? in .h or .m file ?

Comment: @rajesh: If you want to use your table's variable at anywhere in .m file then you have to declare it in .h file (for variable's scope).

Comment: I have posted my question in following link check and reply to me I need your help       [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333897/how-can-i-reload-the-tableview-that-listed-in-rootviewcontroller-m-from-category)

Answer (score 0):

from the class itself `[self RefreshTableView:yourTableView];`

form outside of the class `[yourClassInstance RefreshTableView:yourTableView];`

P.S: 
You should refactor your code and rename `RefreshTableView:` with `refreshTableView:`

Comment: What you mean by it does not work? Do you have values in your data source array? Do you set the correct number of cells and rows? Do you display the data in the cellForRow?