# How can I reload the tableView that listed in RootViewController from a category table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, listview

I'm doing a joke app. The home page is list of categories that listed in `RootViewController` from a category table.

The database is updated when the user performs changes. The problem is when I come back to the home page, the table is not refreshed.
Changes are visible when I run the app again.

I tried `[tableView reloadData]` and `[self.tableView reloadData]` but with no result.

Here the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{       
    return 1;
}   

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
      WhySoSeriousAppDelegate *appDelegate = (WhySoSeriousAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication               sharedApplication] delegate];

      return appDelegate.jokes.count;
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{       
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ] autorelease];

        UIView *activeColor = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        activeColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170/256.0 green:50/256.0 blue:0/256.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = activeColor;          
    }       

    WhySoSeriousAppDelegate *appDelegate = (WhySoSeriousAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Joke *joke = (Joke *)[appDelegate.jokes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   

    [cell setText:joke.category];       
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;       

    return cell;        
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: you have to reload the datasource in rootviewcontroller ie fetch data from database again

Comment: reload the table in ur viewWillAppear of ur RootViewController

Comment: Are you grabbing the latest data from your database before using [self.tableView reloadData]?  Just a guess but you may be reloading the table's data without first updating that data.

Comment: " WhySoSeriousAppDelegate " !!! good one ...

Comment: @Aalok Parikh, How can I fetch the data from database again? Can you explain about it?

Comment: @vishy, I tried the [tableView reloadData] but doesn't work.. Is there any other way or else Im doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Squatch, I do update the database when the button pressed. that's I really want list the data again...but i don't know how to do that? how can i call the RootViewController again? Is it possible?

Comment: @Maulik, thank you man...can you help me out from this problem?

Comment: @rajesh Sorry, let me rephrase that. You may be reloading the table's data without first grabbing the newest data from the database. Reloading simply repopulates the table, so if the data it is reading has not been changed, you are just going to redisplay your old records. I don't know where it is that you are querying the database but you need to do that again before reloading your table's data. You may want to create an object of RootViewController or use static methods.

Comment: @Squatch, you mean repopulating by writing the above code in some where else?

Comment: @rajesh The code you have above looks ok. The question is 'Where are you querying the database?' You MUST be querying the database for the data every time you open the app. It looks like you may be doing that in the app delegate, so make that a method and call it every time you want to reload the table data. As I mentioned before, using an object or static methods is the way to do this.

Comment: @Squatch, I tried what u said above...I ll try it once again and keep looking at my post tomorrow bc I'm going try this in morning..thank you for your and keep looking my post

Comment: Where are you having a code to retrieve data from database? Call that method before reload tableView in viewWillAppear: method.

Comment: @R.A, i ll try and come back to you

Comment: Hi every one I tried almost everything but no result found..thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code for update Your UITableview:

```
    [table_view beginUpdates];
    [table_view deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [table_view insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [table_view endUpdates];
```

Thanks...!

Comment: Where I have to write these coding?

Answer (score 0):

Reload the Joke data either in app delegate on in same controller to see the changed records. And then reload the table view.

Comment: hey, How to Reload the joke data?

Comment: Populate the data same as you have populated for 'appDelegate.jokes'.

Comment: Where I have to write the code populate the data again? If i do write RootViewControoler the both function get loaded at first time it ll not get loading after my change. And v can't use UITableView function inside of our function because its default for Xcode

Comment: you can reload the Joke object data inside viewWillAppear of RootViewController method and then reload the table view.

Comment: I tried some kind of code to reload but no result.. Can you write example to reload the object(joke)?